# Using ServiceStack Client with Case Sensitive REST Service

Tags: c#, json, rest, servicestack

My code is using a `DataContract` with `DataMember` in the response DTO and
I'm attempting to consume a REST service with this response but it's not working:

```
{
 "results": {
  "p": 277.76,
  "s": 1,
  "x": 11,
  "P": 34.95,
  "S": 3,
  "X": 51,
  "z": 3,
  "T": "ABCD",
  "t": 1625874938819163000,
  "y": 1625874938819148500,
  "q": 55320377
 },
 "status": "OK",
 "request_id": "e16e9db61563c8f675d5400f6c9fd8c9"
}
```

As you can see the names are case sensitive and I'm pretty sure that is the reason.  I found [this article from 9+ years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772449/using-servicestack-client-with-non-servicestack-rest-services) that states:

> As for ServiceStack's JSON Serializer, in the latest release - the properties are case-insensitive...

So the questions if it wasn't obvious, is there's a way to work with a case sensitive names.  Hopefully its just a config option that I need to set or something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServiceStack.Text Json Serailizer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) properties is case-insensitive, so you would need to use a Dictionary instead to be able to capture properties with different names, e.g:

```
class ApiResponse
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you can use [HTTP Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) to consume the 3rd Party API then parse the adhoc JSON with [JS Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) which will deserialize it into the appropriate collection type and also preserve the types that is was returned with, e.g:

```
string json = url.GetJsonFromUrl();
var obj = (Dictionary<string,object>)JSON.parse(json);

obj["T"] //= "ABCD"
obj["t"] //= 1625874938819163000
```

Comment: I'm sure this is something you've considered but PLEASE add an option for case-sensitive deserialization because although it is possible it seems that 10years later using another deserializer is really the only practical solution.

Comment: @LorneCash wont happen, reason for case insensitive deserialization is accommodating poor data which has no business in a typed class with public properties and  as a result have no intentions increasing complexity or perf cost by adding an additional option. My answer shows different ways to cater for poor data, otherwise you'll need to use a different serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set JSON mapping to be case insensitive, so mapping will work regardless of the case

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};
var weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(jsonString, options);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing

Comment: I'm aware of `System.Text.Json`, my question is if ServiceStack can be forced to be case sensitive because it isn't by default.